# multiple method invocation in EJB2.0 session bean

Tags: java, oracle, transactions, ejb-2.x

I have one session bean with following method

```
/**
  *  This method is used to Update Voucher Expiry Date and Voucher Status for Voucher Service
  * @ejb.interface-method
  * @ejb.facade-method invalidate="true" 
  * @ejb.transaction type="Supports" 
  * 
  * @return ResulObject, Which contain Success Or Error Code as a Response Code
  * 
  */

 public ResultObject updateVoucherDetails(VoucherServiceData voucherServiceData){
    IPINSessionBeanLocalHome pinSessionBeanLocalHome=getPINSessionBeanLocalHome();
    IPINSessionBeanLocal pinSessionBeanLocal = pinSessionBeanLocalHome.create()
    pinSessionBeanLocal.changeVoucherStatus(voucherStatusChangeData,sessionInfo);
 }

 /**
  *  This method is used to Change Voucher Status
  * @ejb.interface-method
  * @ejb.facade-method invalidate="true" 
  * @ejb.transaction type="Supports" 
  * @return ResulObject, Which contain Success Or Error Code as a Response Code
  * 
  */

 public ResultObject changeVoucherStatus(VoucherStatusChangeData voucherStatusChangeData,ISessionInfo sessionInfo){

 }
```

When i call `changeVoucherStatus()` directly data successfully updated in database.

but when I have called `updateVoucherDetails()` , data for `changeVoucherStatus()` method did not update into database , even I have found log printed inside `changeVoucherStatus()`

Can anybody tell , what is going wrong ?

Comment: Why is ejb.transaction "Supports" ? Seems like you want it to be "Requires" no ?

Comment: I have checked the same with Required also

Comment: Can you try specifying transaction attribute as `REQUIRES_NEW` for `changeVoucherStatus` method.